# Name that Country!

Tags: knowledge, geography

What country does the following text represent?

**Forward By confidence, we Union seek justice, peace and the sword.**

Comment: Are the capitals intentional?

Comment: Yes they are!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Malawi

Because we know from my previous answer,

> Massachusetts's state motto is: Ense petit placidam sub libertate quietem, meaning roughly: By the sword we seek peace, but peace only under liberty correlating to: "we Union seek justice, peace and the sword"; Louisiana's state motto is: Union, justice, and confidence, "We Union seek justice..." "Forward by confidence; and Wisconsin's motto is "Forward", the first word of the riddle

We can put it all together, and we get:

> The first two initials of Massachusetts; MA, the abbreviation of Lousiana, LA, and the Abbreviation for Wisconsin., WI. Putting these together, we get Malawi, a country in Africa.

I'd like to thank humn for helping me realize the correlation with the state names.

Comment: You nailed it! Great job!!!! :)

Comment: BTW I believe it's the only country whose name is entirely comprised of a combination of 2-letter state abbreviations! :D

Comment: Nice answer. Though FBu looks like the currency of Burundi, with Kwacha for Malawi.

Comment: @Tom Yeah FBU wasn't part of it, but I love the creativity! Those words were capitalized because they are the first words of each state's motto.

Comment: What is this "we union" you speak of? I can't parse it. Are you going for "we, the union. . . "? Is it supposed to be the union of the set `we` and `seek justice`?

Comment: @terdon, I think it may have been in there to throw us off

Comment: The text in the post is the words from the three states' mottos, rearranged. I had to scramble them to occlude them from google searches, and to make the puzzle more interesting.

Comment: @wildBillMunson, I still figured out that they were state mottos through Google search :P

Comment: Haha well I guess that didn't work! Outsmarted by Google once again... :D

Answer (score 2):

The country is

> Norway,because the initials spell out FBU. This is the airport code for Fornebu airport,Oslo

Comment: Sorry that's not it. +1 for the try though...

Answer (score 1):

> The United Kingdom.

This is because you capatilized:

> Forward, Confidence, and Union, and the Five Brigades Union is the United Kingdom.

I didn't find any further evidence for the United Kingdom, so I very well could be wrong.

Comment: Nice try but that's not it. It's a bit more cryptic than that. There is another reason why those words are capitalized. +1 for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

> Burkina Faso, because the clue is a reference to the country's motto

Comment: How so? Remember that you're supposed to explain the process you used to get to your solution.